# QuickFix initiator application logout when recieved a logon message

Tags: authentication, quickfix

I testing out a quick fix 4.4 api.
The problem:
Right after, the program sending the logon message (line 3), the server responds with a logon message (line 5).
But then QuickFix calls on LogOut instead of LogIn.
The log:

```
2020-09-16 12:46:21.917 [Information] on OnCreate
2020-09-16 12:46:22.366 [Information] on ToAdmin
2020-09-16 12:46:22.388 [Information] on 8=FIX.4.49=11235=A34=249=Q01352=20200916-02:46:22.36656=XCD3298=0108=30141=Y553=test_q554=10=229
2020-09-16 12:46:22.721 [Information] on FromEarlyIntercept
2020-09-16 12:46:22.722 [Information] on 8=FIX.4.49=7035=A34=149=XCD3252=20200916-02:46:23.05356=Q01398=0108=30141=Y10=080
2020-09-16 12:46:22.774 [Information] on OnLogout
```

The response from the server seems alright.

Where is my problem?

Comment: Maybe because the 52/SendingTime on the incoming Logon is in the future?

Comment: Thanks @ChristophJohn, I found the problem, it was not related to the time, but good point. There is a time difference between client and server. I will post the issues as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem from reading the logs generated by the FileLogFactory.
The logs shows:

```
20200916-04:18:35.816 : Initiated logon request
20200916-04:18:36.096 : Message 1 Rejected: Required tag missing (Field=554)
```

It is then very obvious. I have the password field in FIX44.xml to be Required. But the message return from the server does not have a field as such. So I guess, quickfix think it is an error and discount?
After modifying the field to required='N', things go expected.